# Firefox/Chrome Button to bookmarklet

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking into creating an extension for Firefox/Chrome that creates a button in the toolbar. When clicked, it should load a bookmarklet (basically a piece of js).

Any good resources to start with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the browser itself, you would need to create an extension, not a bookmarklet.

Bookmarklet are just javascript code that will be executed when you add a bookmark on the toolbar (or anything) that has code. If that is the UI your looking for, then that is great. Just create something like:

```
javascript:alert('bookmark clicked');
```

If you want a browser action, you need to package it up as an extension. For Google Chrome, you can visit the docs and API http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html there are many examples on how to create one by searching StackOverflow.

For example:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert('brower action clicked');
}));
```

To build an extension in Firefox, you would need to follow their guide here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you can use the [Custom Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/custom-buttons/) extension. Not sure but [Custom Toolbar Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bgkppjihbcfjacahlodggdefnfjiflfe) extension for Chrome might allow executing your bookmarklet as well - or you can use it as a starting point for your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar, so that I could do a focus group to see whether users prefered an extension to a bookmarklet.  All I did was create a very basic extension that just executed

```
location.assign("Your bookmarklet contents here");
```

This is pretty much functionally equivalent to a user clicking the bookmarklet on a web page. The only real difference I had to account for was making sure the page was done loading before running that.  That may not be an issue for your needs, but it was for mine.